# Selenide SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error.Any thoughts?

Tags: java, maven, selenide

I am new to Selenide, and trying to run a browser using Selenide and Junit dependencies. However, I am getting an

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error.Any thoughts?

```
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>1</groupId>
<artifactId>1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide -->
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
```

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.close;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;

public class ChromeStart {
    @Before
    public void RunURL() {
        Configuration.browser= "chrome";
        open ("http://google.com");
    }
    @Test
    public void StartBrowser() {
        System.out.println("Hello world")
    }
    @After
    public void CloseURL(){
        close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this error is a result of the missing dependency.
Try to add a following dependency to your pom.xml file and run your test again.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4jnop</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```